# Is it possible to add or change a GCP compute engine service account using powershell?

Tags: powershell, gcloud

When migrating compute resources into GCP, they don't get assigned a service account or API access.
I have some knowledge with powershell and I'd like to be able to assign a service account and set of API permissions using that instead of having to learn python or another language.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any programming language for that. Before migrating you will need to create and configure GCP project [with a script](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp) (recommended) or [manually](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/configuring-gcp/configuring-gcp-manually).
After migration you can [create and enable](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances) additional service accounts and [change API access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).